# Replace $sanitize implementation in angular with DOMPurify?

Tags: angularjs, security, xss, angularjs-1.6, dompurify

Is it possible to replace native implementation of $sanitize function from angularjs (version 1.5.x) with custom implementation that would use [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)?

My goal is to be able to write [`ng-bind-html=value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) and have DOMPurify being used when sanitizing HTML.

Comment: Use a [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) to replace the core [ng-bind-html directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) with one that uses DomPurify. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - How to use decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators#how-to-use-decorators)

Answer (score 3):

You can use DOMPurity to sanitize the data before rendering it. If so, just don't inject `$sanitize`.

In terms of XSS security (as you tag it), note that DOMPurify [is **not** made to work with AngularJS](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/wiki/Security-Goals-&-Threat-Model):

> DOMPurify will NOT prevent you from XSS caused by crazy library
>   features as for example AngularJS has. We implemented a protective
>   coat to protect against jQuery-XSS but cannot cover all other
>   libraries. If you are using a library that has crazy XSS
>   vulnerabilities or you are not sure if that is the case please talk to
>   us. See also: [JSMVCOMFG](http://www.slideshare.net/x00mario/jsmvcomfg-to-sternly-look-at-javascript-mvc-and-templating-frameworks), [mustache-security](https://code.google.com/p/mustache-security/), [jPurify](https://github.com/cure53/jPurify)

Comment: I would prefer DOMPurify to be called even in cases when a ng-bind-html instruction is being used and a developer forgot to call DOMPurify before rendering data

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the [`ngSanitize` module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize), just provide your own implementation for `$sanitize`:

```
angular.module("yourModule").factory("$sanitize", () => html =>
  DOMPurify.sanitize(html, {
    SAFE_FOR_JQUERY: true,
    // ... other settings
  })
);
```